# Does car window glass visibility reduce cumulatively on application of sunfilm?

Tags: windshield, window

Say my car window glass has come with a visibility of 70% (VLT).
Now, say if I apply sunfilm having visibility (VLT) of 70%, then does the overall visibility of window reduce to below 70%?
will it be like 70% of 70% = 49%

Comment: It isn't that simple.  The variability of the attenuation over the spectrum will be different for the two attenuators.  Thus the cumulative dB drop will vary across the spectrum.  Any polarisation effects would also affect the cumulative attenuation.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: @Chenmunka Sorry, that's too much technical for me to understand. I get from you that there are too many parameters involved in the calculation and it can't be 49%. Could you please tell me in simple whether the cumulative visibility would be at 70% only or will it be less than 70%?

Comment: For the total to be 70% it would mean that sunfilm applied to any tinted glass would be completely ineffective, and as some tints are very slight (and there is no 100% transparent glass), at what level do you suppose the film would lose its efficacy? If they are both polarized in different directions it might be close to 0. It isn't a simple multiplication.